# Using Outlook 2007 for two accounts but configuring one for sending by default.

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, gmail, yahoo-mail

I currently use outlook 2007 to manage two email accounts, but I want to set one address so all sent emails come from that address by default.

Currently all emails come in regardless of the account, but I want all responses to send from a specific email address.  How do go about this?

All my emails come in from my current provider yahoo, but I'm not happy with them I and want everything to transition to go out from my new gmail account.

Comment: you have any luck figuring this out?

Answer (score 3):

This is easily done in the account settings inside the outlook account settings under tools.

Once both accounts are setup, select Tools from the Menu, and select Account Settings.

[image: Tools]

From Outlook 2007 Account Settings:

- Highlight the desired account
- Click Set as Default
- Now click Close

You now have one account set as default, from now on, all e-mails (including replies) will be from the account set as default.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select that E-mail send from which mailbox in new message windows as below: ( sorry this screenshot is from outlook 2013 but outlook 2007 has same option)
[image]

or Change your default e-mail account as below:
[image]

Answer (score -3):

This is better done directly in Gmail rather than Outlook.

In the Gmail settings, you can get it to read the Yahoo mail, it will come into the Gmail mailbox. The mail will then be treated as Gmail anyway, no need to mess about with multiple accounts in Outlook.

Comment: Sheesh - someone else who downvotes without the common courtesy to say why so that people can improve answers.

Comment: I didn't down vote but I would guess it was because you weren't answering the question but providing more of an opinion. I would guess the OP wanted to use desktop software instead of a web app for a reason.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question I would think.

Comment: It does answer the question! Google provide a direct facility for doing what the OP wants and it is much better than trying to do this with Outlook. The underlying message of the OP is that they want to move away from Yahoo mail, my answer gives them the best mechanism for doing that.